# How to fetch the name of all user on remote server which is present at 'C:\user' folder and write that name into Excel file

Tags: windows, powershell, script, shell-script, .bash-profile

I am trying to get the name of all users of multiple server through powershell and than transfer it to excel file but I only got the name of user in txt file and unable to copy it to excel.

Foreach($Computer in get-content D:\Discserver.txt) { $win7= Test-path C:\users If(win7 -eq 'true') {$win7users=(get-itemproperty -path C:\users* -exclude Admin,Administrator,public,temp,updateuser,'All users' ,user).name} Write-host user list: - foregroundcolor green $win7users Out-file -filepath c:\userinfo.txt -inputobject (new-object -typename String -argumentlist "user list:") -Append Out-file -filepath c:\userinfo.txt -inputobject $win7users -Append ##method that I have to used to write it in excel are below #open the workbook $XL = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application $WB = $XL.workbook.open("c:\userinfo.xlsx") #Activate sheet1,pipe to out-null to avoid 'true' output to screen $WB.Sheets.Item("Sheet1").Activate() | out-null #find first blank row #, and activate the first cell in that row $FirstBlankRow = $($XL.Activesheet.usedRange.Rows)[-1].Row + 1 $XL.ActiveSheet.Range("A$FirstBlankRow"). Activate () [Array]$users={$win7users} [Array]$Record=[PSCustomObject]@{ 'Users' = $users[0] } $Record += $users | Select -Skip 1 | foreach{[PSCustomObject]@{ '$users' = $_ } } $Record | ConvertTo-Csv +Delimeter "`t" -NoTypeInformation $XL.ActiveSheet.Paste() $WB.save() | out-null $Wb.close() | out-null $XL.Quit() | out-null

Comment: can anyone please help me to get the solutions of this script in simplest and short way. Thanks in advance

Comment: PLEASE fix the horrible code formatting. i can't tell where lines are supposed to end ... and will not fight thru that for free. [*grin*] the instructions on code formatting are linked on the page you used to create your Question.

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-list-all-user-profiles-on-a-remote-computer/ and https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-get-the-list-of-user-profiles-on-your-computer

Comment: `foreach ($Computer in (Get-Content -Path 'C:\servers.txt')) { (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Computer\c$\Users" -Directory).BaseName }` then  just pipe to any `Export-*` cmdlet. You can also *invoke* the command and have it sent over to perform the query, but for something this minimal there's no need.

Comment: I don't wanna be "*that*" guy but, please actually try an actual code attempt instead of copying and pasting random code. We're here to help, so any effort is appreciated on your part. I'd also recommend querying CIM with one of the CIM cmdlets such as `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName blahblah` for a more reasonable approach since you're querying actual profile instances and not just folders.

Comment: Don't just copy./paste and run stuff. You can destroy/cause serious issues in your environment/data. Why on earth are you trying to do this as a one-liner? Do this one step at a time, one thing at a time, in a real editor (ISE/VSCode, etc., so it can prompt and show you your results and errors as you try each step. ***There is so much wrong with this code.***

Comment: Abraham  what should I do after foreach ($computer in (Get-content -Path..... Because it gives me the name of users but how I can transfer this name to Excel?.. I am able to fetch the name but unable to move this name to Excel. Thanks in advance @Abraham

Comment: @Postanote I just write the code from my system to my mobile.. I didn't know why this is not written in normal format..

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I didn't know why this is not written in good format because I just write manually all the code in question section but it's finally show in horrible type..

Comment: @Drmoishe thanks but I also want to know how I can move this name to Excel.

Comment: Well if you have the excel module, you can just pipe (*like I've already mentioned*) to any `Export-*`. So `.. | Export-Excel -Path C:\parh\blah.xlsx`. or, `Export-Csv`. Or any export cmdlet

Comment: @Catherine - take a look at this help topic >>> How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML? - Help Center - Super User — https://superuser.com/help/formatting

Comment: Your question was closed yesterday because it lacked details and/or clarity. **Please do not delete your old question and repost it without first addressing those points.**

Comment: Hi @Abraham ,Now i am able to run my script. Thanks a lot